# How to get count of friends of friends

Tags: python, django

i am building a website like instagram where users can follow friends, i have been able to implement follow friend and also displaying friends of friends (mutual friend). I was not able to get the count of friends of friends; this is what i tried:

Model:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,null=True)
    friends = models.ManyToManyField('Profile', related_name="my_friends",blank=True)
```

view:

```
@login_required
def profile_user_view(request, username):
    #Friend of Friends
    p = Profile.objects.filter(user__username=username).order_by('-id')
    all_friends = request.user.profile.friends.values_list('pk', flat=True)
    friends_of_friend = Profile.objects.filter(pk__in=all_friends)    
context = {
    'profile_img': p,
    'friends_of_friend': friends_of_friend,
}
return render(...)
```

Template:

```
{% for data in profile_img %}
{% for friend in friends_of_friend %}
{% if friend in data.friends.all %}
<li>
<a href="{% url 'site:profile-view' friend.user.username %}" class="dark-grey-text">
   <b>{{ friend.user.username|lower }}</b>
</a>
</li>
<li>
    {{ friend.count }} #This is not showing the count of friends of friends, when i use length it displays '0 0' instead of '2' (mutual friends)
</li>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `friends_of_friend.count` to get count of current user's friends. If you want every friend's friend count then use `{{ friend.friends.count }}`.

Honestly, you do not need this much context in template. You can access them all from `{{ user }}` attribute in template. For example:

```
{% for friend in user.friends.all %}
  Username {{ friend.user.username | lower }}
  Count {{ friend.friends.count }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I am not getting the correct count for each users (friends of friends). Why does it shows count 3 if a user only have 1 friends of friends? Or should this be a problem on how I query for friends of friends in views.py?

Comment: Please check the database to see how many entry has been created for friends of a friend. I do not think it is related to the query in view

Comment: When I check the database it creates an entry, from_user_id and to_user_id who sent and accepted request.

Comment: What should be the problem why friends of friends count is not accurate?

Comment: Hello can anyone help me out, I have been on this finding solution but no help. Someone please help

Answer (score 0):

i know it is late but ....

utils.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from collections import Counter
#this function finds friends_of_friends_id
def friendship(user):
    a = User.objects.get(id=user)
    return [i.id for i in a.profile.friends.all()]
#this function will take return all your friends's id with how many mitual_friend you have together
def count_mitual_friends(user_id):
    return  Counter([foaf_id for friend_id in friendship(user_id)
                for foaf_id in friendship(friend_id)
                if foaf_id != user_id
                and foaf_id not in friendship(user_id)
                ])
```