# How do I create custom users permission

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create a custom user permission. When user A block user B, when user B login and try to access user A profile through url (localhost:8000/user_a_profile/) it should show 404 Forbidden, but user B can be able to access other users. I have found out the way to do this is to create a decorator.py, i have done that and i have a problem. I have created a decorator.py, but when user A block user B, when user B login and try to access user A profile through url, the reverse is the case. User B was able to access user A profile (which is wrong) but when i try to access other users profile, i get 404 Forbidden. How do i set only user A to show 404 Forbidden when user A already blocked user B, and user B can access other users. But it seems my code is working in u-turn.

Model

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,null=True) 
    blocked_users = models.ManyToManyField('Profile', related_name="blocked_by",blank=True)

class Blocked(models.Model):
    user_is_blocking = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='user_is_blocking', null=True, blank=True)
    user_is_blocked = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='user_is_blocked', null=True, blank=True)
```

Decorator.py

```
from django.core.exceptions import PermissionDenied
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from pixmate.models import Profile,  Post

#Blocked users can not find current user profile in url
def user_is_blocked(function):
    def wrap(request, *args, **kwargs):
        profile = get_object_or_404(Profile, user__username=kwargs['username'])
        if Profile.objects.filter(blocked_users=profile):
            return function(request, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            raise PermissionDenied

    wrap.__doc__ = function.__doc__
    wrap.__name__ = function.__name__
    return wrap
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an decorator like

```
def user_is_blocked(function):
    def wrap(request, *args, **kwargs):
        profile = get_object_or_404(Profile, user__username=kwargs['username'])
        if Blocked.objects.filter(user_is_blocking=profile.user, user_is_blocked=request.user):
            raise PermissionDenied
        return function(request, *, **kwargs)

    wrap.__doc__ = function.__doc__
    wrap.__name__ = function.__name__
    return wrap
```

We need to check either the requesting user is blocked by the user we are looking at the profile of (In your code you did not check for requesting user anywhere), So we need to use the Blocked object, and search on it if any object for blocked model exists which has requesting user in attribute user_is_blocked and the user we want to fetch profile of in user_is_blocking.

Comment: @Sami..Can you please check on this question, i have not been able to solve this problem.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62425657/how-to-get-count-of-friends-of-friends/62426190?noredirect=1#comment110405531_62426190